# CORS request to cloudfront missing cookie

Tags: jquery, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I am logging into https://subdomain1.domain.com and sending a POST request to https://subdomain2.domain.com. I am having the below code in my Ajax request as the request is cross domain.

```
xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
      },
      crossDomain: true,
```

I have also setup CORS configuration in Cloudfront

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://subdomain1.domain.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-Requested-with");
```

There was an OPTIONS request before the POST request and it responded with 200. For the post Request, I received 404 as the backend is not fully setup, but when I inspect the element in firefox, I cannot see cookie in the request itself which I was expecting it to be.

Did i do anything wrong or missed anything?

Comment: Is the cookie actually set in your browser after logging in?

Comment: yes, it was set after logging in. But, it's somehow not being set when made request to subdomain2.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the cookie attribute named `Domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value)? Are you using it to set your cookie? If you want the browser to attach your cookie to requests sent to subdomains of `domain.com`, you need to set the cookie in question with `Domain=domain.com`.

Comment: The set-Cookie is done by the server, correct? But the request to the server itself misses the cookie header. I even further tried to add the set-cookie header on cloudfront layer, but that header is not allowed to be added in the response headers policy.

Comment: Yes, `Set-Cookie` is a response header (written in HTTP responses by servers). Do you not control the server at `https://subdomain1.domain.com`?

Comment: The ajax code is running on an ec2 instance and i am using a test environment, https://subdomain1.domain.com to access the pages. I am not sure to confirm if i own the server at https://subdomain1.domain.com.

Also, there is existing code for the same package with same origin and it works. i am only changing the endpoint behind a button which is now https://subdomain2.domain.com and for which I have added the xhr configuration on the client code.

Comment: Let me rephrase: can you change the way the cookie is set on the server side? If so, you'll need to set it with a `Domain` attribute. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: When I go to the storage tab in inspect in firefox browser, I can see the cookies for the  https://subdomain1.domain.com and the domain for each cookie is .domain.com. Doesn't that mean that the cookie can be shared with other subdomains?

The page that i am working on is one of the pages of the main website and I think the cookie generates when logged into the web initially before going to the page I am working on.

Comment: _Doesn't that mean that the cookie can be shared with other subdomains?_ Yes, that's correct. It should work... Let me think about it.